# Django issues creating a custom user model

Tags: django, authentication

I trying to switch to a custom User Authentication so I can make changes more easily to the user model when needed. I was looking at the documentation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/ but I am now having an issue with my forms.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser


class DefaultUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    pass
```

Forms.py Contains the following

```
from .models import DefaultUser
from django.core.validators import EmailValidator
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
from django.contrib.auth import password_validation
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UsernameField

class UserCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given username and
    password.
    """
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),
        'Invalid_Email_Address': _("Invalid Email Address"),
    }
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password confirmation"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        strip=False,
        help_text=_("Enter the same password as before, for verification."),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = DefaultUser
        fields = [
            "username",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
        ]
        field_classes = {'username': UsernameField}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self._meta.model.USERNAME_FIELD in self.fields:
            self.fields[self._meta.model.USERNAME_FIELD].widget.attrs.update({'autofocus': True})
            self.fields[self._meta.model.USERNAME_FIELD].label = 'Email'

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        validate_username_is_email = EmailValidator()
        print(username)
        print(validate_username_is_email(username))
        if validate_username_is_email(username):
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['Invalid_Email_Address'],
                code='Invalid_Email_Address',
            )
        return username

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
        return password2

    def _post_clean(self):
        super()._post_clean()
        # Validate the password after self.instance is updated with form data
        # by super().
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password:
            try:
                password_validation.validate_password(password, self.instance)
            except forms.ValidationError as error:
                self.add_error('password2', error)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

The error I get happens when I try and run migrations is
**django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (first_name, last_name, username) specified for DefaultUser** Which seems to be caused by the class Meta in my form because if I take away a field the error changes. Though when the Meta was pointing to model = User everything was working fine.

Also, I did add this to my setting page

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.DefaultUser"
```

And admin.py has

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import DefaultUser

admin.site.register(DefaultUser)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[AbstractBaseUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser) class does not contain any model fields ( except password and last login fields) so this cannot function even in theory. You should define model fields in your DefaultUser model class for it to use, check [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example).

Also admin part wont function as you haven't registered it's Admin class.

If you read this documentation a bit more carefully you should get it eventually.

[AbstractBaseUser](https://github.com/django/django/blob/48c17807a99f7a4341c74db19e16a37b010827c2/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L47) class you can check in source also [BaseUser](https://github.com/django/django/blob/48c17807a99f7a4341c74db19e16a37b010827c2/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L285) for some hints

Comment: So I tried making the changes in the full example but I am having an issue still running migrations I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'accounts.DefaultUser'" The app is called accounts, I have also given it the namespace accounts. Then inside models.py the class is named DefaultUser. Am I doing something wrong here?